# How to handle share popup in chrome using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, video-capture

I am trying to record a tab in chrome. I found an extension that does this called `Screen Recorder`. I will access it using this link `chrome-extension://hniebljpgcogalllopnjokppmgbhaden/index.html#/` after I download the .crx file and load it. After some configuration, I hit start record and it opens a popup where it tells me to choose the window, tab or screen. I need to interact with that popup to choose which tab to record. I tried using AutoIt but it couldn't identify or interact with that popup. Is there another way to interact with the share popup ?